# My texture will only show up in solid shading, not rendered or material preview

Tags: texturing, shaders

I am new to blender and am having trouble rendering my texture. I have my model compleated and the texture mapped onto it but am not sure why it will not appear in renders or material preview. I've look at this question but am not sure if I made a similar mistake. ([my texture to shows up in solid mode but not material preview mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203783/my-texture-to-shows-up-in-solid-mode-but-not-material-preview-mode)) Please let me know if i should include any other images in this form.[image: My Screen]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're in Material Preview mode rather than Solid in that second image? Hover over the R/H window and hit Z for the pie menu to see and change what mode you're in.

Comment: Yes, I kept switching back and forth, I was in material preview, the first image is the solid mode

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (don't forget to pack your image: File > External Data > Pack Resources)?

Comment: Looking at your images the first looks like a material preview (although the icon shows it's set to solid) and the second looks like solid mode so I'm not sure what's going on there. I agree with @moonboots that we need to see the blend file which you can share via https://blend-exchange.com/.